# Swipe to Reveal for deleting item in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have successfully implemented swipe to reveal in my list of items. I have added a delete icon in the hidden menu. When I click the delete item, the items gets deleted from the mutableStateList and the list gets updated with the remaining items. The only problem is that then the item next to deleted one has its delete icon visible (the hidden menu revealed already).

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: I had the same problem. I have solved it by closing the delete button before deleting the item. However, i think you can give a key to each item and since the item with key removed, it can close the button? I haven't tried it but it can work

Comment: I tried the key thing already but it didn't work @Subfly

Comment: It was useful, I am also now before removing the item. But the other thing is, how to close the revealed menu of an item by revealing the ui of another item. Like I want maximum to have only one item with its side menu open.